# How do I create a dataset using computed values?

Tags: r, dataset, aggregate

Please see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LSLvcImyNBG1-gVUrRZaOs_nCk4dZIMq9bPMDIaCeVQ/edit?usp=sharing) the input and desired output tables.

I have a dataset (df_report) that looks like this:

```
city <- c("New York","Mexico City","Cape Town")
A <- c(3,4,1)
B <- c(5,1,3)
C <- c(0,3,2)
category <- c("Complete","Incomplete","Complete")
df_report <- data.frame(city, category, A, B, C)
```

Then the logic/ formula for the variables:

```
RB_1 <- df_report["Complete","A"] + df_report["Complete","B"]
RB_2 <- sum(df_report["Incomplete",]) - df_report["Incomplete","C"]
RB_3 <- sum(df_report["Complete",])
RB_4 <- RB_1 + RB_2
```

How do I make a separate dataset with the following? Row header: Variable; Column: City

Comment: How your result should looks like?

Comment: Do you want to create a data frame with specified column names like so: `RB_4 <- data.frame(Variable=RB_1, City=RB_2)` or what?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. The output should be, rows are RB_1, RB_2, etc. Columns are cities.

Comment: I want to make one summary table with Rows as the computed variables, and columns as the cities

Comment: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) **along with the desired end result**. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks. For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables` and `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Comment: There's no row name `'Complete'` so `df_report["Complete","A"]` results in `NA`. Did you mean `df_report[df_report['category'] == "Complete","A"]`? The latter subsetting results in vector of two elements - what should be a desired value of `RB_1`?